# php check session data against URL parameter

Tags: php, session

I am new to php and having trouble with the following. I want to check the session user name to see if it matches the url parameter then print some stuff:

```
<?php

  // Check User
    if (isset($_SESSION['user_name'] == $_GET['name'])) {

        //print html

    }
?>
```

i just get a blank page when i test this even when the session name matches the url name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to start your session and you're using `isset()` incorrectly

```
<?php
  session_start();
  // Check User
    if ($_SESSION['user_name'] == $_GET['name']) {

        //print html

    }
?>
```

Better and more complete solution:

```
<?php
  session_start();
  // Check User
    if (isset($_SESSION['user_name']) 
        && isset($_GET['name']) 
        && $_SESSION['user_name'] == $_GET['name']) {

        //print html

    }
?>
```

Comment: `isset($_SESSION['user_name'], $_GET['name'])` returns true only if both `$_SESSION['user_name']` and `$_GET['name']` are set. And it's shorter to write.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you compare boolean result of isset function with string name from url.

```
  // Check User
    if (isset($_SESSION['user_name'])&&isset($_GET['name'])) 
      if (($_SESSION['user_name'])==($_GET['name']))
{
        //print html
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

start session before checking session like this

```
<?php
   session_start();
  // Check User
    if (isset($_SESSION['user_name']) == $_GET['name']) {

        //print html

    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

logic error in `isset()` function, do so:

```
if (isset($_SESSION['user_name']) && isset($_GET['name']) && $_SESSION['user_name'] == $_GET['name']) {

    //print html

}
```

upd: and sure, `start_session()` before any actions with session variables